# The keys installed for kernel module signing in Ubuntu 20.04 do not seem to be in /proc/keys

Tags: kernel

I have built a package which requires a kernel module.  It uses the /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic/scripts/sign-file executable to sign a kernel module and here sign-file uses the der and priv files in /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der and /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv. When I try to install the kernel module, the insmod command fails and dmesg tells me the .ko file is unsigned, although I can verify with modinfo that it is in fact signed.

I looked in /proc/keys and verified that the signer is not listed, i.e.

sudo openssl x509 -in /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der -inform der text

shows the signer (common name) is ubuntu Secure Boot Module Signature key, which is not one listed in /proc/keys.

I think I can fix it by giving the command

sudo mokutil -import MOK.der

but isn't this something which the 20.04 Ubuntu install should have done?